# How to configure Jenkins to run tests on a physical Android device?

Tags: android, jenkins, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am using Jenkins and espresso to run my automation tests. Is there any possibility to configure Jenkins in order to run my tests on a real Android device instead of the simulator ? Thank you.